# Notification Bar and Home button not working

Tags: internal-storage

I have moto G3 in it the home button, notification bar and recent button is not working. Tried to do factory reset but that option is also not working. tried to switch off the phone remove sim card and SD card, but still no luck.
Please advice !

Comment: Did you disable SystemUI?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the troubleshooting steps

1. Ensure the device is powered off, and unplugged
2. Press and hold the Volume Down button and Power button (located on the right edge of the device) for approximately 3 seconds then release.
3. From the "Boot Mode Selection Menu" screen, select Recovery.

Note: Use the Volume Down button to scroll through the menu options and the Volume Up button to select.

4. From the "No Command" screen (Android figure lying on his back), press and hold the Power button then press and release the Volume Up button to display the menu options.
5. Select "wipe data/factory reset".

Note: Use the Volume buttons to highlight and the Power button to select.

6. Select Yes -- delete all user data.

Note: Allow several seconds for the factory data reset process to complete.

7. Select reboot system now.

Note: Allow several minutes for the reboot process to complete.